# Proof about elementary group theory

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory

12. Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and $σ : X → X$ be a bijective function. 1) Prove
    that $σ^n$ is invertible for all $n ∈ N$. 2) Prove that there is an natural number
    $n$ such that $σ^n = I_x$. Hint: Use PHP to show that there are natural numbers
    $l > k$ such that $σ^l = σ^k$ and use the fact that σ_k is invertible to conclude that $σ^{l−k} = I_{x}$.

what is $σ^n$?. Is it a permutation on n elements? or the n permutation?. For the first question, do we have to show that there exists a bijection from n elements to n elements?. What is PHP?

Approach  if $σ^n$ is one to one then if $σ^n(x)=σ^n(y)$ then $y=x$

$$σ^n(x)=σ^n(y)$$
$$     σ(σ^{n-1}(x))=σ(σ^{n-1}(y))         $$

we know that $σ$ is injective so by exahustion $x=y$ which implies that $σ^n$ is injective.

Comment: $\sigma^n=\sigma\circ\cdots\circ\sigma$ n-times, i.e, the n-th iterative application of the given bijection $\sigma$. I don't know that $PHP$ is, but I would just use the fact that there is a finite number of bijections from a set to itself, and then use part $1$.

Comment: so I have to prove that $σ^n$ is bijective?

Comment: PHP = pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Yeah: invertible is nothing but bijective.
Thanks @JohnHughes, it's exactly why the argument I have written down, works.

Comment: is my argument valid to prove it's one to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this post is about elementary group theory, I hope you are familiar with the group of permutations $S_n$.

$\sigma$ is a permutation on $5$ elements and $\sigma^{n}$ is the composition of $\sigma$ applied $n$ times.
ie. $\sigma^n = \sigma \circ \sigma \dots \circ \sigma$ applied $n$ times.

Since you have $\sigma : X \to X$, and $X={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}$, you can think of $\sigma$ as a permutation in $S_5$ that maps each element in $X$ to another element in $X$. We can simple use the fact that $|S_5|=120$ to solve the problem.

For the first question, obviously $\sigma ^ {n}$ is invertible for all $n \in N$ since if $\sigma \in S_5$, $\sigma^{n} \in S_5 \quad \forall n \in N$, and every element in a group has an inverse, so $\sigma^{n}$ is invertible.

For the second question, the easiest way to do it is to show that:
$\forall \sigma \in S_5$, $\sigma^{120}=I$.
Since $|\sigma| \mid |S_5|$ (since $S_5$ is a group), we must have $\sigma^{120}=I$, and we are basically done.

Comment: wouldn't it  be any multiple of 5 for the second bullet point?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, consider a 2-cycle in $S_5$. Applying the same 2-cycle 5 times will not get you the identity.

Comment: I know what you are doing, you are basically taking into account every cycle to get back to the identity. That's why it is 5!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to associate to $\sigma$ a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) $P_{\sigma}$ in $GL_5(\mathbb{Z})$. Then $\det(P_\sigma)=\pm 1$, because $P_{\sigma}$ is invertible with coefficients in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. Clearly then $\det(P_{\sigma}^n)=\det(P_{\sigma})^n=\pm 1$ as well, hence the matrix $(P_{\sigma})^n$ is invertible for all $n$, which is equivalent to say that the permutation $\sigma^n=\sigma\circ \cdots \circ \sigma$ is invertible.

Comment: It's much easier, and more general, to just give the explicit inverse $(\sigma^{-1})^n$, is it not?

Comment: XD, I am not even in the abstract algebra class yet. I am just taking a course about intro to mathematical proof. Anyways, it's useful for more knowledgeable readers.

Comment: @b00nheT "Much easier" depends on the viewpoint. Usually, linear algebra is "much easier" than group theory; and if you can use matrices and determinants, then some people prefer this. Of course, you are right for question 1), but in general, permutation matrices are useful and easy.

Comment: yes, they are very useful in various applications, so it's indeed a good idea to use them on easier problems first, so to get used to them.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) we may use induction over $n$: Clearly $\sigma$ is invertible as a bijective function (or if you define zero to be in $\mathbb{N}$, then clearly $\sigma^0=I_X$ is a bijection), and if $\sigma^n$ is invertible, then $\sigma^{n+1}=\sigma\circ\sigma^n$ is invertible as the composition of two invertible maps (check: what is the inverse map to $\sigma^{n+1}$?).

For 2) note that since $X$ is finite, there are only finitely many maps from $X$ to $X$, thus there must be some $l,k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $l>k$ such that $\sigma^l=\sigma^k$. It follows that $\sigma^k=\sigma^l=\sigma^k\circ\sigma^{l-k}$ and applying $\sigma^{-k}$ (which is meant to be the inverse to $\sigma^k$) on both sides (from the left) yields $I_X=\sigma^{l-k}$.

Comment: I have the same idea for the first bullet point right?